# Is it possible to start a TCP socket connection without a handshake?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, scapy

I am making a SSL server, and I don't use python's library as I want to make some unorthodox changes to the process. Because of that, I cannot simply start a TCP connection since I need to transfer the encryption details with the handshake, which I can't do over sockets. So I am using scapy to make the handshake itself, but after that I would like to continue working with a TCP socket without going through the process of the handshake again. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you exchanged a few segments using scapy and now want to manufacture a normal full-blown socket out of them.

This is not easily possible: for all practical purposes your TCP is oblivious to whatever you sent in your packets and it doesn't keep any state for this TCP connection: all the state is in your application.

That said, there is a thing called [`TCP_REPAIR`](https://criu.org/TCP_connection) in Linux that lets you put a socket in a given state.

> When this option is used, a socket is switched into a special mode, in
>   which any action performed on it does not result in anything defined
>   by an appropriate protocol actions, but rather **directly puts the
>   socket into a state, in which the socket is expected to be at the end
>   of the successfully finished operation**.

If you set sequence numbers correctly, the socket should "just work".,

> One also needs to restore the TCP sequence numbers. To do so, the
>   TCP_REPAIR_QUEUE and TCP_QUEUE_SEQ options were introduced.

Of course all this is specific to a modern Linux; other operating systems may or may not have similar mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you. I do not run Linux, is there a possibility to cast a socket from UDP to TCP after I perform the handshake? Also, I heard about "Raw Sockets". Is it possible to use that all the way instead? I haven't read about raw sockets yet, but if you happened to know this is possible with that method than I will study about them.

Comment: @jep_macca "is there a possibility to cast a socket from UDP to TCP" absolutely not. Raw sockets won't help you here: by definition raw sockets have no transport-level semantics.

Comment: Well thank you very much for all the help. I will look for a TCP_REPAIR for Windows, hopefully there is such thing. Making a TCP connection would be pretty tiresome with UDP connection and timeouts.